How can you more effectively create data frames from a list after using lapply?
I'm a beginner to using R - I learnt some at University for econometrics, but we were only taught how to perform linear regression and other statistical tests, but were given very little info on creating data frames, manipulation etc.
I've used Codecademy's course to get a bit more of understanding and was introduced to list.files() and lapply().
I want to list a number of files by a pattern using list.files, then read those files using lapply() into a variable. This all works well.
My issue is when I want to assign each file to a separate data frame from the variable I created using lapply(), I'm doing it by calling on individual elements of the list variable created using lapply(). Is there a more efficient way of doing this, e.g., by iterating over the list variable and assigning each one to a different variable?
Note: it's very possible my terminology and even understanding is completely off. There may be a more effective way of doing this that doesn't use list.files or lapply. I would appreciate any guidance, even if it's clarifying my wording!
This is my current code:
testscores <-  list.files(pattern="ExamResults.*csv")
testscoresdfs <- lapply(testscores,read_csv) # This reads the list in testscores into dataframes, and saved them as separate elements in testscoresdfs (a list)

Eres <- testscoresdfs[[1]]
Sres <- testscoresdfs[[2]]
Mres <- testscoresdfs[[3]]

The final three lines is what my question pertains to -- is there a way of more effectively loading each individual element of testscoresdfs to a separate variable that isn't having to calling it our individually? Would I need to reiterate over a the list of testscoresdfs and another list of dataframe names, e.g. dfnames <- [Eres, Sres, Mres], then do something like:
for (i in testscoresdfs) {
 for (j in dfnames) {
  code
 }
}

Again, it's possible that in reality, I don't want to be doing this and my rudimentary knowledge makes me think I do!

It is usually best not to leave a bunch of data frames loose in the global environment especially when you intend to iterate over them.
Using the input in the Note at the end, since the file names do not have any obvious relationship to the names you want to use in R create Files which defines the relationship.  Then we can read them using lapply creating L and iterate over L with whatever function we want f creating L2.  L$Eres and L2$Eres can be used to refer to specific components.
Files <- c(
  Eres = "ExamResults1.csv",
  Sres = "ExamResults2.csv",
  Mres = "ExamResults3.csv"
)

L <- lapply(Files, read.csv)

f <- function(x) head(x, 2)  # misc code
L2 <- lapply(L, f)

str(L2)
## List of 3
##  $ Eres:'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
##   ..$ Time  : int [1:2] 1 2
##   ..$ demand: num [1:2] 8.3 10.3
##  $ Sres:'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
##   ..$ Time  : int [1:2] 10 20
##   ..$ demand: int [1:2] 83 103
##  $ Mres:'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
##   ..$ Time  : int [1:2] 100 200
##   ..$ demand: int [1:2] 830 1030

If you have control over the filenames then just rename them as
Eres.csv, Mres.csv and Sres.csv in which case we can create Files from them and then continue as above.  tools comes with R so it does not need to be installed.
    Files <- Sys.glob("?res.csv")
    names(Files) <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(Files)

Note
Create some test files using the built-in BOD data.frame.
write.csv(BOD, "ExamResults1.csv", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(10 * BOD, "ExamResults2.csv", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(100 * BOD, "ExamResults3.csv", row.names = FALSE)


You're probably looking for list2env. This, as the name implies, turns a list into an environment, with elements in the list as objects in the environment. If you specify the global environment, then the list elements will be available as if you assigned the object individually, as you show
l <- lapply(1:3, seq)
names(l) <- LETTERS[1:3]

sum(ls() %in% names(l))
# [1] 0

list2env(l, .GlobalEnv)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

sum(ls() %in% names(l))
# [1] 3

Normally this isn't recommended, as you'd quickly end up with conflicts. It's better to keep the dataframes in the list, and use with(), *apply() and so on to handle them.
